# Setting multiple img alt listeners with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, listener, alt

I have a loop through a set of keys that creates event listeners based on their values.

```
for (var keys in key) {
    if (excludeList.indexOf(keys) == -1) {
        d3.selectAll('img[alt="' + keys + '"]').on('click, function() {
            console.log(keys);
            d3.selectAll('img[alt="' + keys +'"').style('opacity','0.5')
        })
    }
}
```

Every listener overrides the previous one, such that the last key is the only listener remaining.

How can I set listeners on different alt tags?

Comment: Is `excludeList` being populated anywhere else? And could it possibly have the previous `keys` in it already?

Comment: Nope @sebastianForsberg

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos I'm trying to set event listeners for different alt tags. Every time I set one, it overwrites the previous event listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking for array/object values, but for indexes (`keys` vs. `key[keys]`, or semantically correct: `key` vs. `keys[key]`).

Here's a fixed example:

```js
var keys = {
  a: 'shomz' // 'In code veritas' not listed so no event
 ,b: 'another'
}

var excludeList = ['excluded'];

for (var key in keys) {
  if (excludeList.indexOf(keys[key]) == -1) {
    attach(keys[key]);
  }
}

function attach(k) {
  $('img[alt="' + k + '"]').click(function() {
    console.log(k);
    $('img[alt="' + k + '"').css('opacity', '0.5')
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt="In code veritas" />
<img alt="shomz" />
<img alt="another" />
<img alt="excluded" />
```

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I did need the keys. Your code produces the same result for me, always rewriting the alt selectors such that the last key is the only listener setup.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean... it's a standard issue with loops and delayed events in JS, see my update. I moved the code to external function which takes an argument in order to pass the key value at the time of the loop execution, not after the loop terminates.

Comment: The externalized function did fix the issue. How strange.

Comment: It's fairly common in JavaScript. As I said, it happens when calling deferred events from loops, expecting the iterator to have the value from the moment the call was made, but instead getting the value from after the loop has finished (at the time of the actual code execution).